# SQL Pivot numerous records, string data

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have three columns each of which are NVARCHARs. My first 'Id' column appears numerous times for each instance of the second column for which data is held (in the third column.

I have tried to use the pivot operator but I am having trouble using string data with it.

Table example:

```
RecordId    QuestionText              Data
1           Completion Date           26/01/2016
1           Gender                    M
1           PreCourse Info            2
1           Application Process       1
```

Pivot Requirement Example:

```
RecordId  Completion Date Gender Precourse Info Application Process
1         26/01/2016      M      2              1
```

Apologies for the pants table layouts above.

There is a large amount of data (1595 distinct RecordIds) and approximately 50 rows for each RecordId.

I have tried the following after reading some posts:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
       RecordId
      ,QuestionText
      ,Data

    FROM #PrePivot
) AS P
PIVOT
(
Data FOR QuestionText 
)   AS Pvt
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you could advise if there is something missing in my code or if it would be better not using the pivot operator.

Thanks for your time

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH PivotData AS
(
    SELECT
    RecordId,
    QuestionText,
    Data
    FROM #PrePivot
)
SELECT RecordId, [Completion Date], [Gender],[PreCourse Info], [Application Process]
FROM PivotData
PIVOT( MAX(Data)FOR QuestionText IN ([Completion Date], [Gender],[PreCourse Info], [Application Process])) AS P;
```

Two comments:

1. You have to explicitly specify the list of columns that you want to see in the output.
2. You have to use some aggregation function. However, we actually don't want to calculate any aggregation here. Instead we only want to display the content of *Data* column. It is why I used `MAX` function. It will work assuming that for a given *RecordId* there are no duplicates in *QuestionText* column.

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for the post, this works perfectly. I have a problem with the size now of the column names and they need to retain the same names for the end users reports. I am going to pass this now to our web developer as he has said that he can do this and provide a front end for our users. really appreciate the post being so prompt and so correct.